# Axes tick rotation depending on position in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Calling `plt.spines.set_position()` appears to be overwriting the tick labels rotation, but not the labels themselves. Before I call `.set_position()`, `rotation=` seems to be working as expected:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'type': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'height': [1, 2, 3]
})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(8,2))

df.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)

ax.set_xticklabels(['zero', 'one', 'two'], rotation=90)
```

[image]

When then when I call `.set_position()`, the labels still appear, but they revert to their original rotation:

```
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('outward', 10))
```

[image]

Is there a way to call `.set_position()` while retaining the label rotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple. Put the set_xticklabels statement after set_position():

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'type': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'height': [1, 2, 3]
})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(8,2))
df.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('outward', 10))
ax.set_xticklabels(['zero', 'one', 'two'], rotation=90)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This works! Thank you. Can you edit to explain why it's necessary to put them in this order?